# Is there a way to directly replace a table in a ppt slide with officer?

Tags: r, powerpoint, flextable, officer

I've built out a shiny app to allow a few users within my organization to upload data, and print some tables to ppt. There is more information in the ppts than can be directly coded through shiny.

At present, they download the ppt and then copy and paste the new tables over the old ones, is there a way within officer to directly replace a table?

i.e.

```
ppt <- read_pptx("pptexample.pptx")

ppt$directory.to.object$object.name <- new.flex.table
```